# the conection was opened and closed but no row inserted to my database?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, insert, database-connection, row

I'm using visual studio 2010 and microsoft sql server 2008.

this is my procedure code:

```
 PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsUpdUser]
(
    @UID nchar(10),
    @FName nchar(20),
    @SName nchar(20),
    @LName nchar(20),
    @UT nchar(6),
    @PWord nchar(4)
)
as
BEGIN
    -- add NEW record
    insert into UserT ([UID],FName,SName,LName,UT,PWord,QC)values(@UID,@FName,@SName,@LName,@UT,@PWord,0);


END
```

this the code for the class:

```
Public Class DataAccsess
    Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=822-PC;Initial Catalog=ICDLDB;Integrated Security=True")

    'open connection to the database
    Public Sub dataAccess()
        con.Open()
        MsgBox("opend")
    End Sub
    'close the connection to the database
    Public Sub CloseCon()
        con.Close()
        MsgBox("Closed")
    End Sub

Public Sub addUsers(ByVal UID As String, ByVal fName As String, ByVal sName As String, ByVal lName As String, ByVal UserT As String, ByVal Pword As String)
        Try
            Dim PAS As String
            Dim com As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("InsUpdUser", con)
            PAS = (UID).ToString.Substring(UID.ToString.Length - 4)
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            com.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@UID", UID))
            com.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@FName", fName))
            com.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SName", lName))
            com.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@LName", sName))
            com.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@UserT", UserT))
            com.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Pword", PAS))



        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)

        End Try
    End sub

End Class
```

the button code:

```
Try    
            Dim da As New DataAccess

            da.opencon()

            Dim ID, FN, SN, LN, UT, PWord As String
            ID = TextBox2.Text
            FN = TextBox3.Text
            SN = TextBox4.Text
            LN = TextBox5.Text
            UT = DropDownList1.SelectedItem().Text
            PWord = "0"


            da.AddUser(ID, FN, SN, LN, UT, PWord)

            da.closecon()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)

        End Try
```

So
the code run
I insert all the info in the textboxes and 
the MsgBox("opened") pop up
then 
the MsgBox("closed") pop up
nothing happened
no row inserted in the database
no row appear on the viewGrid.
nothing happened
I was using the express sql that come with the visual studio 2010, and the same thing happened.
my friend tell my to remove it and download the microsoft sql server 2008.
I did that but the same problem.
No Row add.
the procedure 
was executed in the sql server.
when I create the connection.
the connection test pop up that connected successfully.
the connection in the run opened and closed.
but no row add.

hope I find any one can help me in this.

Thanks

Comment: In `addUsers` you are creating the parameters but where is the `Execute` command?  Try adding the line `com.ExecuteNonQuery()` after you create you parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overwrite your exist Sub with this and it should work. You are missing the execute command and either the sub is named incorrectly or the call to it is incorrect.  Either way they need to match.

```
Public Sub AddUser(ByVal UID As String, ByVal fName As String, ByVal sName As String, ByVal lName As String, ByVal UserT As String, ByVal Pword As String)
        Try
            Dim PAS As String
            Dim com As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("InsUpdUser", con)
            PAS = (UID).ToString.Substring(UID.ToString.Length - 4)
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            com.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@UID", UID))
            com.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@FName", fName))
            com.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SName", lName))
            com.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@LName", sName))
            com.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@UserT", UserT))
            com.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Pword", PAS))

            com.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)

        End Try
   End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a spelling mistake at AddUser.change it to AddUsers like the following one.

```
 da.AddUsers(ID, FN, SN, LN, UT, PWord)
```

and also change the parameter add to the following

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", UID)
```